# Does .net create instance per Test Method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, tdd

My question is about the way .net running **test methods**. Let's say that I have a test class like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
        {
            ...
        }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

**Question is does .net create an instance per each of these test methods? or it will create just one instance of MyTestClass and will run all the test methods over the same instance?**

Comment: You could write a test for that :)

Comment: For example, log a message or set a breakpoint in the constructor

Comment: Yes it is. I looked for the same question about a year ago, but can't provide you proof link right now. MS Test creates new instance for isolation between tests. It means you can create state in test class by giving value to class members and be sure no test will get values set by other tests. Just remember not to use static unless you want to share this for all tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "MSTest instantiates each test method’s class separately during the execution process, with each instantiation occurring on a separate thread"

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nnaderi/2007/02/16/that-pesky-mstest-execution-ordering/